# Passing an object array as TempData[] to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tempdata

I would like to return two values from a post action to the view in a `RedirectToAction` . `TempData[]` seems like the ideal option , as the data is only used to show a success message once the user has saved.

I would like to show a small thumbnail of the image that the user just saved and the title of the saved item, in the success message.

Currently I am passing all the data as a `new MvcHtmlString`

```
TempData["SaveMsg"] = new MvcHtmlString("<img src=" + model.ImageUrl + " //> <h3//>" + model.Name + " has been saved.<//h3//> " ) ;
```

I would like to send it as an `object[]`

```
TempData["SaveMsg"] = new object[]{model.ImageUrl , model.Name}
```

Then I would be able to pass the objects into an `HtmlHelper` and write the conditions for the message display.

I just do not know how to access the object in the view

```
@TempData["SaveMsg"][0] // (O.o) // Error Cannot apply indexing with 
                                 //  [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You access them in a view by casting them to an object array first then indexing them i.e.

```
@{
  var objectArray = (object[]) TempData["SaveMsg"];
}

@objectArray[0]
@objectArray[1]
```

[**.Net fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RYeFRY)

Comment: I would add another point for the .NET fiddle .. if i could . cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
@TempData["SaveMsg"][0] will not work.
```

Try something like this

```
obj[] saveMsgs = (obj[])TempData["SaveMsg"];
```