# C# MVC Saving multiple search strings for pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search, viewbag

I've seen examples on here for saving one string to pass onto the next page. But, I haven't been able to find or figure out how to save multiple search parameters without requiring a variable for each search string, which is something I'd rather not do, as I have 12 search fields.

I've seen examples with saving your variables to a viewbag and then passing that when you go to the next page. That works for the one variable, but not for multiple.

Is there a more eloquent solution then to have to pass individual view bags for each variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you pass an object in the viewbag with your said with variables as properties? ... Like a `Dictionary` key being search field, value being variable value.

Comment: It seems to me that the information should be part of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `class` for it like this:

```
public class SearchField
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    // other fields
}
```

And save object to `ViewBag` like this:

```
SearchField objSearchField = new SearchField();
objSearchField.Field1="value1";
objSearchField.Field2 = 100;
// set other fields
ViewBag.SearchFields = objSearchField;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewbag or tempdata["stringid"]. tempdata might be a better choice here. What you will do is create an array of strings (or a list might be even better!) and store all your information in that array. Then you store it on tempdata. Something like this:

```
 string[] URLs = new string[12];
 //do stuff
 Tempdata["URLs"] = URLs;
```

When you get to the page you need the URLs in again, either in the controller or in the view you will write:

```
string[] URLS = (string[])Tempdata["URLs"];
//do stuff

or 

string[] URLS = Tempdata["URLs"] as string[];
```

Something like that should work. You should read up on the other ways to pass data in ASP MVC:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/

[Passing an object array as TempData[] to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510101/passing-an-object-array-as-tempdata-to-view)